# How to run django remotely?

Tags: python, django, remote-access, remote-server

I'm running `Yang Explorer` in my remote Ubuntu Server.

I run it using `start.sh` in the repository.

```
Activating virtualenv ..
Starting YangExplorer server ..
Use http://localhost:8088/static/YangExplorer.html    
Performing system checks...    
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
January 31, 2019 - 08:35:31
Django version 1.8.3, using settings 'server.settings'
Starting development server at http://localhost:8088/
```

I would like to open the application in my browser using my machine. The IP address given for the server is `152.66.xx.xx`

Comment: Check the README at https://github.com/CiscoDevNet/yang-explorer, they have mentioned how to do it in Section 3.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running with ip-address (Shared server) 
Start Server:

Determine  using if-config

Add `ip-address/port` in `YangExplorer.html` after following line:

```
cd <install-root>/yang-explorer/server/static
vi YangExplorer.html

var flashvars = {}; 
flashvars.host = '<ip-address>';
flashvars.port = '8088';
```

save & quit

Update ip-address in startup script

`cd <install-root>/yang-explorer
vi start.sh`

```
(update HOST variable with <ip-address>)
```

save & quit

`./start.sh`

Note: sudo may be required if you did not use virtualenv during installation.

Start Explorer:

`http://<ip-address>:8088/static/YangExplorer.html`